# In-House Distribution - Xamarin and VS2019 Version

Tags: xamarin, enterprise, in-house-distribution

I was wondering whether I need the Enterprise version of VS2019 to create In-House Distribution for Xamarin.iOS Apps or Pro would suffice? 
Also, what would be benefit for Mobile when using Enterprise vs. Professional?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we check Compare [Visual Studio 2019 Editions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/),we will find each version has all the features of the previous version, as well as additional features.

With Visual Studio Professional, it’s an excellent choice for most developers. For software architects though, Visual Studio Enterprise might make sense, as long as you have plenty of budget.  But if you don’t, a lot of plugins in the Visual Studio ecosystem can help you get VS Enterprise’s features in ala carte fashion.

For creating In-House Distribution for Xamarin.iOS Apps, `the Visual Studio Community` is suffice, let alone `the professional version`.

[image]